# Changing CheckBox states in facebox using jQuery / AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebox

I am using jQuery AJAX to dynamically load web user control's HTML via web service into one of my `<div>` element.
This works absolutely fine, without any problem.

The problem arises when I use `facebox` plugin to show that `div` as a popup. I have Select All / None checkboxes in this `div` which should select all checkboxes or deselect all of them.
When I click the links *select all* / *none* and try to select all checkboxes through jQuery,  nothing happens and nothing reflects on my checkboxes until I close my popup and reopen it.
As soon as I reopen my popup iIcan see that all checkboxes are checked.
What might be the problem?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code, but my guess would be you need to use the .live() method on the checkboxes within the facebox div, since the facebox renders after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of your code, it's a little difficult to really understand what you want, but I'll make a guess.  Here's one way to make a "select all" checkbox:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="select-all" id="select-all" value="select all" />
<label for="select-all">Select All</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" value="5"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#select-all").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        $(".checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $(".checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```